# Execute code as string vb.net

Tags: windows, vb.net

Is this possible to do?

```
Public Function MyFunc() as Integer
        dim I as integer
        Execute("I = 50")
        Return I
End Function
```

I mean can I execute code like that in a function?

Edit1:
I asked another question here:
[Checkpoints in functions VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425339/checkpoints-in-functions-vb-net)

I have a Queue in there name of labels ,  when I dequeue I want to run something like this:

```
Dim Queue as new Queue(of string)
Queue.Enqueue("Checkpoint1")
 Queue.Enqueue("Checkpoint2")
Dim i =Queue.dequeue()
GoTo I
```

But I can't set this labels dynamically
and I wanted to know is there any way to achieve sth like this or not?

Comment: No, VB.NET is a statically compiled language. You can't dynamically compile text mid function and have local variables in scope.

Comment: Where does your string `"I = 50"` come from?

Comment: @Enigmativity OK! Thanks

Comment: @Enigmativity  I am building that in same scope

Comment: Is that the answer to my question?

Comment: @Enigmativity yeap, but for more information for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425339/checkpoints-in-functions-vb-net. I am trying to create GoTo label statements dynamically

Comment: I don't know what "I am building that in same scope" means in relation to "Where does your string `"I = 50"` come from?".

Comment: @Enigmativity ok!! your right. Is there anything can to do about this question?

Comment: Can you explain where `"I = 50"` comes from?

Comment: @Enigmativity I just edit my question

Comment: @muffi how can I do this?

Comment: What you're asking for is quite ridiculous.  What you need to do is restructure your code and then you won't need to dynamically jump to labels.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that was just an idea and I'm looking for better ones I don't want to do that or I would do that if there is a way

Comment: For instance, put each section of code in a method and then create an array of delegates to each of those methods.  You can then execute each delegate in sequence or by specific index.

Comment: @muffi, the need to "access dynamically" doesn't in any way make the request any less ridiculous. What needs to be done is the ultimate aim analysed and achieved in an appropriate manner.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok Let me see if I can do this or not

Comment: I just want to optimize my code on performance and stability and write less codes unless I can check my dequeue value in a switch case and run it normally

Comment: @AliTheOne - Where does the `"I = 50"` in the queue come from? I want to know the original source of the `"I = 50"`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just edit my queation

Comment: @AliTheOne - This is such an X-Y problem! You can easily do what you want with a `Dictionary(Of String, Action)`. You should have been much clearer from the beginning. This whole business with `"I = 50"` was a waste of time. I have to run at the moment, but I'll try to put an answer together for you later.

Comment: @AliTheOne - I've put an answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your linked question, here's the kind of thing that you need:

```
Dim choices = New Dictionary(Of String, Action) From
{
    { "Apple", Sub () Console.WriteLine("I Love Apples") },
    { "Banana", Sub () Console.WriteLine("I Go Ape Over Bananas") }
}

choices("Banana").Invoke()
```

This outputs `"I Go Ape Over Bananas"` to the Console.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440962/259769 for a more specific implementation that you need.